# Powershell compare-object output 1 line per item

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I am attempting to put the output of compare-object. I am new to Powershell and unfortunately don't know the ins and outs yet.

My command is as follows:

```
Compare-Object -referenceObject $(Get-Content "c:\temp\mek\123-first.txt") -differenceObject $(Get-Content "c:\temp\mek\123-second.txt") | %{$_.Inputobject} | sort-object | out-file "c:\temp\mek\results.txt"
```

The contents of my files are as follows (simply comparing Windows services):

```
systemname name                                         state   startmode
---------- ----                                         -----   ---------
D7MCYP     AdobeARMservice                              Stopped Auto     
D7MCYP     AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc                    Stopped Manual   
D7MCYP     AeLookupSvc                                  Stopped Manual
```

My results of the compare-object are as follows:

```
BL3C4V     wudfsvc                                      Stopped Auto
BL3C4V     wudfsvc                                      Stopped Manual   
D7MCYP     AdobeARMservice                              Running Auto     
D7MCYP     AdobeARMservice                              Stopped Auto
```

Now if anyone could help output to keep the first 2 columns per server and the different values of columns 3,4 to new columns (5,6). It would also be nice if I get titles too. For example:

```
Server      Service             Before State    Before Mode     After State  After Mode
BL3C4V      wudfsvc             Stopped         Auto            Stopped         Manual
D7MCYP      AdobeARMservice     Running         Auto            Stopped         Auto
```

Comment: its you wicj build file ? dou you can use csv?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wicj build file"... No, I am not using CSV, but rather exporting the data to a plain old txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: The code below is **an exercise in parsing plain-text data into objects for more robust, flexible handling**.

Ideally, however, processing should *start out* with objects rather than plain text,
 which is why **starting with *PowerShell cmdlets* such as [`Get-Service`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) rather than the text output from *external utilities* is preferable.**</sup>

Assuming that all entries in each input file have a matching server + service-name entry in the respective other file:

```
$f1, $f2 = "c:\temp\mek\123-first.txt", "c:\temp\mek\123-second.txt"
Compare-Object (Get-Content $f1) (Get-Content $f2) | ForEach-Object {
    $i = 0; $ht = @{}; $vals = -split $_.InputObject
    foreach($col in 'Server', 'Service', 'State', 'Mode') {
      $ht.$col = $vals[$i++]
    }
    $ht.Before = $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='
    [pscustomobject] $ht
  } | Group-Object Server, Service | ForEach-Object {
      $ndxBefore, $ndxAfter = if ($_.Before) { 0, 1 } else { 1, 0 }
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Server = $_.Group[0].Server
        Service = $_.Group[0].Service
        'State Before' = $_.Group[$ndxBefore].State
        'Mode Before' = $_.Group[$ndxBefore].Mode
        'State After' = $_.Group[$ndxAfter].State
        'Mode After' = $_.Group[$ndxAfter].Mode
      }
    } | Sort-Object Server, Service |
      Format-Table
```

Note:

- The above formats the output for display (using `Format-Table`), without sending it to a file.
  You can append `| Out-File "c:\temp\mek\results.txt"` to save the same representation to a file.
- However, note that the command - before `Format-Table` is applied - returns *objects* with individual properties, so you can output to a file in a variety of formats, such as by using `Export-Csv`, for instance.

Example output:

```
Server Service                   State Before Mode Before State After Mode After
------ -------                   ------------ ----------- ----------- ----------
D7MCYP AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc Stopped      Manual      Stopped     Auto      
D7MCYP AeLookupSvc               Stopped      Manual      Started     Manual
```

---

**Explanation**:

A single, long pipeline is used, which makes the code concise and memory-efficient.
The pipeline breaks down as follows:

- Comparison:

  - `Compare-Object` compares the array of lines from the two input files returned by the `Get-Content` calls, and outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances representing the *differences* found, with string property `.SideIndicator` indicating whether the line at hand (accessible via `.InputObject`) is unique to the LHS (the 1st input file) - `<=` - or the RHS (2nd input file) - `>=`
- Transformation to custom objects:

  - The script block (`{ ... }`) passed to `ForEach-Object` is executed for each input object (represented as `$_`).
  - `-split $_.InputObject` splits the "difference line" at hand into fields by runs of whitespace and stores the resulting fields as an array in `$vals`.
  - `$ht` is an auxiliary hashtable that is used to map the field values to field names.
  - `$ht.Before` adds a Boolean entry to indicate whether the difference line at hand is from the "before file" (the 1st input file) or not.
  - `[pscustomobject] $ht` converts the aux. hashtable into a custom *object* and outputs it (sends it through the pipeline).
- Grouping:

  - `Group-Object` is used to group the resulting objects can by shared `Server` and `Service` property values, resulting in a `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo]` instance representing each grouping.
- Transformation to *combined* custom objects:

  - Again, `ForEach-Object` is used to perform per-input object processing.
  - `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is used to construct each combined output object, again using an auxiliary hashtable.
  - `$_.Group` contains the input objects that form each group - in our case, `$_.Group[0]` and `$_.Group[1]` are the converted-to-objects input lines representing a given server-service combination.
  - By definition, both input objects have the same `.Server` and `.Service` values, so blindly using `$_.Group[0]`'s values for the combined output object will do.
  - By contrast, the `* Before` and `* After` properties the appropriate input object (whether from the 1st or 2nd file), which is why the array indices `$ndxBefore` and `$ndxAfter` are chosen accordingly, via the previously added `.Before` property
- Sorting:

  - `Sort-Object` sorts the resulting objects by the specified properties.
- Output formatting:

  - Output-formatting cmdlet `Format-Table` ensures that the sorted objects are presented as a *table*.